# Shopping Page in Search Query

Tags: seo, google-search-console, url, local-seo

I originally wanted to do eccomerce for my website but I switched it to a service-based website, the site is now live but when I search on Google, the shop is showing up on the organic query(that wasn’t the case at first), turns out I still had some of the shopping page archives live. I went ahead and made them private but it is still showing up on Google’s search query. Is this normal, should I wait a couple of weeks for it to be removed, or is there another way to fix this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Google next does a crawl, it will mark them and eventually remove them.  If you are bothered by them existing right now, you can use the [Google Removal Tool Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en).  It only removes it temporarily and if the page is found, it will be in the search results again.

You do need to make sure that those URLs do not link to a live page.

> **Very important notes:**
>
> - A successful request lasts only about six months. After that, your information can appear on Google search results (see Making removal permanent).
> - Blocking a URL does not prevent Google from crawling your page, only from showing it in Search results. When you request a temporary block of a URL, Google can continue to crawl the URL if it exists and isn't blocked by another method (such as a noindex tag). Because of this, it is possible that your page can be crawled and cached again before you remove or password-protect your page, and can appear in search results after your temporary blackout expires.
> - If your URL is unreachable by Google (404, 502/3) when you use this tool, it will assume that the page is gone, and your block request will expire. Any page found at that URL at a later time will be considered a new page that can appear in Google Search results.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, Rohit!